# App Store ID or Google Play Package Name are not verified

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm have issues to register the facebook app sign in.

I'm currently on TestFlight (iOS) and Close Test (Android).

I've entered the App Store ID and Google Play Package Name but for the second time I have this answer back:

> To keep the Facebook platform and community safe, apps are
> periodically reviewed for compliance.
>
> A warning was sent to inform you that *yourApp* couldn't be reviewed
> because the App Store ID or Google Play Package Name provided could
> not be verified.
>
> Your app's Settings have not been updated. As a result, Amovie has
> been restricted for violating Platform Policy 7.9. To lift the
> restriction and reactivate your app, update your app Settings with the
> correct iOS Store ID(s) and/or Google Play Package Name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am also having this problem, were you able to find a workaround to the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :/